# ActionView::Template::Error (v1_retired):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have an old Rails Application which is working perfectly in development but once pushed to heroku, I get the error 
ActionView::Template::Error (v1_retired):
Here's the link to the [repo](https://github.com/afide26/palmettostudios) of the application.

Thanks for anybody's help in advance.

The error starts when I navigate to the posts path of the application.
Heroku logs show:

```
2017-10-15T06:15:40.681364+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (242.1ms)
2017-10-15T06:15:40.684606+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts" host=palmettostudios.herokuapp.com request_id=7cef0fd8-3df4-4eac-8236-499f871c4949 fwd="61.68.174.8" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=255ms status=500 bytes=1669 protocol=https
2017-10-15T06:15:40.682377+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 247ms (ActiveRecord: 8.3ms)
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683956+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683958+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (v1_retired):
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683959+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:                <p><%= link_to 'Read Full Post', post_path(post), class:'pull-right btn btn-xs btn-link' %></p> 
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683960+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:            </div>
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683960+00:00 app[web.1]:     29:            <div class='col-md-4 col-xs-12 post-image'>
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683961+00:00 app[web.1]:     30:                <%= image_tag(post.image.url, class:'pull-right img img-responsive img-rounded') if post.image? %>
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683962+00:00 app[web.1]:     31:            </div>
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683962+00:00 app[web.1]:     32:        <% end %>   
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683963+00:00 app[web.1]:     33:    </div>  
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683964+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/posts/index.html.erb:30:in `block in _app_views_posts_index_html_erb___362288039534911980_70062267701880'
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683964+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/posts/index.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb___362288039534911980_70062267701880'
2017-10-15T06:15:40.683965+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I just also ran into the same issue for an old Rails app of mine.

For me it was related to using the now deprecated gem `paperclip-dropbox` which relies on Dropbox's [retired API v1](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/).

Hope this information can be useful for everyone who comes here by searching for the non-descriptive error `ActionView::Template::Error (v1_retired)`.